# Angular Material Migration to 15 - MatButton and MatIconButton

Tags: angular-material, angular-migration

After Angular Material Migration from 14 to 15 this error appears:

```
Error: NG0300: Multiple components match node with tagname button: MatButton and MatIconButton
```

Ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 21):

The reason was using mat-button and mat-icon-button on same element

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" mat-button mat-icon-button>
```

To resolve this just use only one.

Comment: awesome! for real it was the case with me too

Answer (score 4):

This was my problem, I had both `mat-icon-button` and `mat-raised-button` on a single button.

`<button mat-icon-button style="margin-top: 25px" mat-raised-button color="primary" >`

When I removed mat-raised-button, its started working again. Thanks to the previous answer!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be an issue if you updated a library which had breaking changes and you messed up the legacy imports.

E.g @angular/material@15 had some breaking changes and renamed their legacy module imports for backward compatibility.
So one had to

```
import { MatLegacyFormFieldModule as MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-form-field';
```

Now if you did that on a top level (e.g. app.module.ts or parent.component.ts) and you did it differntly on the child component

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

Angular would complain, because there would be ambiguous versions of the imported control.